# Tzitzit an appearance in visible form

Tags: hebrew, commentaries, tzitzis, language

[Rabbi Hirsch](http://nleresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Tzitzit-and-Tallit.pdf) seems to have written something like: “tzitzit; indeed it is called tzitzit from the Hebrew root meaning “to appear in physical form.”

Which root is that? And what does this mean in relation to our tassels?

Answer (score 2):

Rashi writes (Bamidbar 15:38)

> ועשו להם ציצת THAT THEY MAKE THEM A FRINGE — It is called צצית, because of the threads that hang down from it. Similar is, (Ezekiel 7:3) “and he caught me by the curls (ציצת) of my head’’. (The word denotes something twisted as threads or curls). — Another explanation is: it is called ציצת because of the command associated with it (v. 39) “and ye shall look at it”. Similar is, “looking (מציץ) from the lattice” (Song 2:9). (The word therefore denotes “something looked at”) (Sifrei Bamidbar 115).
>
> דָּ"אַ: ציצת עַל שֵׁם וּרְאִיתֶם אֹתוֹ, כְּמוֹ "מֵצִיץ מִן הַחֲרַכִּים" (שיר השירים ב'):

The Hak'tav V'Hakabalah writes

> כמו ועשית ציץ זהב טהור, והיינו טס המונח בגובה הראש שהכל מסתכלין בו (שויאבלעך), וכן ציצית הבגדים דהיינו להסתכל בהם (שויאפאֶדען) כמ"ש וראיתם אותו

Indicating that they are a thing made in order to be looked at (as the Ralbag would indicate when he says that purpose is to be looked at "וכאשר יראה בו מצוה אחד ממצות השם יתעלה יזכור את בוראו וירא מלסור מאחרי ה')

(All text from [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.38?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)).

It seems that something looked at would be in physical form.